# how t o change the root directory while building python package using setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py

I have to write a setup.py file and my src tree structure like below

```
──src
  ├───main
  │   ├───python
  │   │   ├───build
  │   │   │   ├───bdist.win-amd64
  │   │   │   └───lib
  │   │   │       └───eapanalytics
  │   │   │           ├───citi
  │   │   │           │   ├───dataproviders
  │   │   │           │   ├───datareaders
  │   │   │           │   ├───datawriters
  │   │   │           │   ├───engine
  │   │   │           │   ├───modeling
  │   │   │           │   ├───schema
  │   │   │           │   ├───transformers
  │   │   │           │   ├───utils
  │   │   │           │   └───validation
  │   │   │           └───resources
```

I want to include the root directory from eapanalytics not from `src.so` how can I write the setup.py to build the wheel.now it creating from `src/---` I want to start only from `eapanalytics/---`.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Use `package_dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages). `setup(..., package_dir={'': 'src/main/python/build/lib'}, packages=['eapanalytics'])` etc.

Comment: @hoefling thanks for your reply..now it creating two directory eapanalytics and src under the tar file.I want one folder eapanalytics and all .py file needs to be under eapanalytics.no need of src/../../ etch under the tar

Comment: The tar is the source distribution that does not resemble the final state of the installed package; when you install the tar with `pip`, `eapanalytics` will be the root package. If you need `eapanalytics` to be the root dir in tar, then place the setup script down the project root, in the `lib` directory and remove the `package_dir` argument.

Comment: ok thanks @hoefling I just want to know what is the significance of build directory?while upload we are passing only dist/* how the build and dist related?

Comment: The `build` directory emerges when you are creating a "binary" package in the sense in that it applies to Python (think `pyc`), e.g. an egg or a wheel. It doesn't affect source dists in any way. The `dist` dir contains the results of the setup script invocation: files that contain the packaged code, source dists, eggs, wheels etc.